# How to test gRPC (functional and integration testing)

Tags: java, integration-testing, functional-testing, grpc, grpc-java

How to test gRPC functional and integration testing? I checked different articles and blogs but found just about unit tests (which doesn't suite). Java.

Answer (score 3):

The Java implementation of the gRPC project has a package to perform unit and integration tests of services.

Take a look at these examples:

- Client Test https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/examples/src/test/java/io/grpc/examples/helloworld/HelloWorldClientTest.java
- Server Test https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/examples/src/test/java/io/grpc/examples/helloworld/HelloWorldServerTest.java

Comment: They use `GrpcCleanupRule` class, but it's not included in the latest `grpc-testing` dependency 1.19.0 which seems to be the latest. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.grpc/grpc-testing Is there a separate example of testing grpc?

Comment: @SergeiLedvanov
I'm sure `GrpcCleanupRule` is in `io.grpc.testing` package.

just add dependency https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.grpc/grpc-testing/1.19.0